# Bootstrap3: Define fixed width of column with more than 12 columns in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3 here.

I have html table having more than 12 rows about 14. These rows are basically input controls like textbox, dropdown etc. I want to define the fixed width of each column. Say for text some width, for text some width etc. I am designing the table as below:

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
          <th>Col4</th>
          <th>Col5</th>
          <th>Col6</th>
          <th>Col7</th>
          <th>Col8</th>
          <th>Col9</th>
          <th>Col10</th>
          <th>Col12</th>
          <th>Col13</th>
          <th>Col14</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="c in data">
          <td>{{c.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <select name="" class="form-control" ng-model="">
                            <option value="">--Select--</option>
                            <option ng-repeat=""></option>
                        </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="" class="form-control" ng-model="">
                            <option ng-repeat=""></option>
                        </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" ng-model="" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried with defining the style on each TH as:

```
 <th style="width:10%">Col1</th>
```

The issue is this works to some extent but as soon as the last few column reach the end of the screen those columns width is decreased automatically even if I define width for them.

I then gave my table width and autoscroll as:

```
style="overflow-x:auto;min-width:100%"
```

But this also doesnt work.

Could anyone point out how to define fix width of each column. I am fine with horizontal scroll.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a fixed width to the form-control class, it will not decrease automatically the width. like this.

```
.form-control {
 width: 150px;
}
```